# Java generic return type for a interface getter (<T> T get();)

Tags: java, generics, design-patterns, interface, return-value

I am working in the design of a SDK that will provide: basic definitions (interfaces), logging and transaction engine for different projects. Each project will be considered as a platform and will be developed as a different project using as basis the SDK; they has similarities but each implementation should be able to solve specific behaviors, however the basic definitions from the core SDK should solve most part of the problems. For example: HUUniversity or MITUniversity

So far I have almost all achieved for example: there is StudentManager interface that provide essential behavior for any implementation:

```
public interface StudentManager<T> extends Manager, Release {
    int getCurrentStudent();
    int getTotalStudent();
    TransactionManager getStudentManager();
    List<T> getStudent();
    void addStudent(T participant);
    T getStudent(String id);
    T removeStudent(String id);
}
```

That way each platform implementation will be able to implement its own definition where basically extend from the basic definition provided within the SDK but the each implementation will be strongly typed and would be able to implement new behaviors:

```
public interface HUStudentManager extends StudentManager<HUStudent>, ParticipantListener {
     List<HUStudentCommand> getCommands(String audioId);
     HUStudent getParticipant(ListType list, String id);
     HUStudent getParticipantByName(String name);
     List<HUStudent> getParticipants(StudentState state);
     List<HUStudent getParticipantsOnList(ListType list);
     List<HUStudent> getParticipantsOnList(ListType list, Sort sort);
     void addParticipantOnList(HUStudent participant, ListType listType, long epoch);
     HUStudentCommand removeCommand(String id);
     HUStudentCommand removeParticipantByName String name);
     void saveCommand(HUStudentCommand command)
}
```

Implementation: the HU platform has its own definition of a StudentManager (HUStudentManager), and extend from the basis (defined on the SDK) since the SDK doesn't know about any HUStudent definition I added a generic param  to it so each

```
public class HUStudentManagerImpl extends HU implements
    HUStudentManager<HUStudent> {

    @Override
    public void addStudent(HUStudent student) {
        if(Utils.isNull(m_students.putIfAbsent(student.getId(), participant))){
            m_totalStudents.incrementAndGet();
            getLogger().log(Keywords.DEBUG,"{0}The instance: {1} with the specified key: {2} has been added to the ConcurrentMap<String, HUStudents>", getData(), student.getClass().toString(), student.getId());
        }else{
            getLogger().log(Keywords.WARNING,"{0}The instance: {1} with the specified key: {2} already exists in the ConcurrentMap<String, HUStudents>", getData(), student.getClass().toString(), student.getId());
        }           
    }
}
```

The sample above works fine and solve the problem where I leave to each developer use his own definitions for the specific platform which of course will extend from the basic definitions

But I wasn't able to figured out how let the developer to use his own definition for a single type within the interface definition ie:

```
public interface Student extends IManager, IRelease {
    UUID getUUID();
    String getId();
    <T> T getSchedule();
    <T> T getElapsedTime();
}
```

I pretend that the basic interface allows to each developer to use its own definition force them to implement a basic behavior or implement a new one but extending from the existing on the SDK:

```
 public interface HUStudent extends Student {
        HUClass getClass()
    }
```

**How can I implement this on the final HUStudentImpl class without get the compiler error in order to suppress the types.** is that possible or should I shadowed the definitions in super class with the desire type

```
 public interface HUStudentImpl extends HU, implements HUStudent {
    //Type safety: The expression of type getSchedule() needs unchecked 
    //conversion to conform to HUSchedule 
    HUSchedule getSchedule(); //Def from Student interface at SDK
    HUElapsedTime getElapsedTime(); //Def from Student interface at SDK
}
```

I cannot use  parameter over the Student interface since each getter could be a different type.

Hope someone can enlighten me and point me in the right direction.

Thanks in advance, best regards.

Comment: On first glance the interface `Student` without a generic type parameter but two generic methods seems off. Why is the interface itself not generic?

Comment: If I make it generic both Types will be the same Type where the interface was declared, just like my first example.In this case I will need to use two different types in the final definition, 
What I am trying to achieve is to define a general behavior, but then each developer can extend from the basic definition and add new behaviors according to the platform, did that make sense?